# how or where add css files in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, css, pythonanywhere

I've made a a app.py and the style's of the dropdown dont open in pythonanywhere

How do I open my stylesheet for the dropdown?

this is the stylesheet:

styles.css

I have a static folder , but don't know how to call the style.css

this is where I call the styles in my .py:

```
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP])
```

what do I change to have also added that style? (how do I call to the static folder or what ever the problem is?)

Comment: On PythonAnywhere you need an extra step of configuring static files mappings on the Web page, see [the documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/).